# Random Island Name

Tags: tools

I know about several random island generators. What I would like is a table or program to generate names of islands randomly.  I found a Greek island version but would like something for English names.

Answer (score 12):

The [Agon island generator](http://axiscity.hexamon.net/users/isomage/agon/island.cgi) generates islands complete with names.

Other than that, I think any random place name generator would work, if you stick "Isle of" on the front or "Island" on the back of it.

Comment: Unfortunately it uses greek style island names. I am looking more for english style.

Answer (score 7):

Just by googling a bit, I found [this one](http://nine.frenchboys.net/country.php). Hope it's useful to you. On the other hand, [this variation](http://nine.frenchboys.net/fantasyplace.php) seems to work better for english names.